# Get all unique pairs in a list, including duplicates, in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

How can I obtain all unique pairs in a list, allowing for repeats?

E.g. for the list `[20, 20, 19]` I'd like `(20, 20)` and `(20, 19)`.

And for `[20, 20, 19, 19, 18]` I'd like `(20, 20)`, `(20, 19)`, `(20, 18)`, `(19, 19)` and `(19, 18)`

I don't really mind what object is returned (list, tuple, dict, set etc) as long as I can then iterate over each pair, and extract both numbers

Comment: One way would be to create a second list that is a list of list, loop through the original list while comparing it to itself, and if the pair does not exist in the second list add it there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> lst_1 = [20, 20, 19]
>>> {comb for comb in combinations(lst_1, r=2)}
{(20, 19), (20, 20)}
>>> lst_2 = [20, 20, 19, 19, 18]
>>> {comb for comb in combinations(lst_2, r=2)}
{(20, 20), (19, 19), (20, 19), (19, 18), (20, 18)}
```

Or just cast into a set directly:

```
>>> set(combinations(lst_1, r=2))
{(20, 19), (20, 20)}
>>> set(combinations(lst_2, r=2))
{(20, 20), (19, 19), (20, 19), (19, 18), (20, 18)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double for-loop where in each iteration, the previous element is removed. I think this solution would be faster than `itertools.combinations` method especially if the list is large, since it doesn't have to find all combinations first.

```
def get_pairs(l):
    out = []
    for i in l:
        l.remove(i)
        for j in l:
            if (i,j) in out or (j,i) in out:
                continue
            else:
                out.append((i,j))
    return out
```

Output:

```
>>> get_pairs([20, 20, 19, 19, 18])

[(20, 20), (20, 19), (20, 18), (19, 19), (19, 18)]
```